# Time taken to reconnect to a BLE peripheral after restored by State Restoration

Tags: ios7, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, ios-bluetooth

Has anyone used State Restoration to reconnect to a peripheral?  if so do you have any feel for the how long it took to reconnect?

It's abit of a difficult question, as it is not easy to tell when to start timing from.

It should be when the iDevice gets in range of its peripheral for which the connection request has been issued.

Comment: Can you describe what you see?

Comment: Haven't tried it yet. It's just that if it takes to long then the user experience will be poor and we will have to rethink. So this is just an enquiry to determine what others have experienced.

Comment: When I was testing background operation, the fastest connection time I could achieve was 7-8 seconds with a peripheral that was advertising as 20ms. This was in the iOS6 days and Apple engineers suggested that this should happen in the order of 1 second. State restoration does not add much overhead. Anyway, this may be worth a test.

Comment: I am surprised you mentioned that your peripheral was advertising, so was this a completely new connection, a peripheral that your central had encountered previously? The situation I am trying to managed is when the central goes out of range, the connection is then lost. The App immediately issues a reconnected, the App is then closed to free up resources. When the App returns within range of the peripheral, the connection should happen it should be restored

Comment: So it is the connect and restoration time, measured from when the central gets within range of the peripheral that I am trying to gauge. This entire operation will operate in the background without the users knowledge.

Comment: If the other device is an iOS peripheral, then the connection can be very slow to establish. Both the central and peripheral slow down drastically in the background which can result is really slow reconnection. Otherwise the peripheral should set the connection interval to a low number to make the connection happen fast.

Comment: I did some vague, ad-hoc testing. I have a peripheral that advertises every second. The reconnection from restoration happened in anything between 6-20 seconds.